# Can't understand this simple matrix multiplication in python

Tags: matrix-factorisation, numpy

Ok guys, I might be very tired here, but I can't figure out why this matrix multiplication by a scalar gives the following result (python)

> **Matrix named 'dx'**
>         [ 1.6,  3.6,  0.4, 14.4, 25.6],
>         [10. , 10. ,  0.4, 14.4,  3.6],
>         [ 0.4,  0. ,  0. ,  1.6, 10. ],
>         [ 6.4,  0. ,  3.6,  1.6,  0.4],
>         [14.4,  0. , 25.6,  0.4,  6.4]
>   
>   **10 * dx, in python, gives** 
>         [ -40.,  -60.,  -20., -120., -160.],
>         [-100., -100.,  -20., -120.,  -60.],
>         [ -20.,    0.,    0.,  -40., -100.],
>         [ -80.,    0.,  -60.,  -40.,  -20.],
>         [-120.,    0., -160.,  -20.,  -80.]

From what I understand, each member should be multiplicated by 10, but it's clearly not the case.

I'm using **Python 3.6 & numpy**

What Am I missing ? 
Link to matrix multiplication by scalar , pretty basic stuff :
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxmult.htm

Thanks !

Comment: I suggest show the complete code to replicate this, it cannot be very long. Very likely you have some other function or effect occurring and you are missing it.

Comment: There is some other function affecting the final value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works for me.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dx = np.matrix([[ 1.6, 3.6, 0.4, 14.4, 25.6],
... [10. , 10. , 0.4, 14.4, 3.6],
... [ 0.4, 0. , 0. , 1.6, 10. ],
... [ 6.4, 0. , 3.6, 1.6, 0.4],
... [14.4, 0. , 25.6, 0.4, 6.4]])
>>> 10 * dx
matrix([[  16.,   36.,    4.,  144.,  256.],
        [ 100.,  100.,    4.,  144.,   36.],
        [   4.,    0.,    0.,   16.,  100.],
        [  64.,    0.,   36.,   16.,    4.],
        [ 144.,    0.,  256.,    4.,   64.]])
```

You might want to check if you have redefined dx before the multiplication.